Set recall request message as read with ItemAdd
I have VBA code in Microsoft Outlook to automatically mark any email added, manually or automatically, to the Deleted Items folder as Read.
In ThisOutlookSession.
Declare DeletedFolder on top of ThisOutlookSession code module (in the declarations area):
Private WithEvents DeletedFolder As Outlook.Items

Then this Sub
Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)   
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then               
        Item.UnRead = False
    End If
End Sub

At the same time there is a rule in Outlook to move some emails to the Deleted Items folder if the sender is someone e.g. ABC@work.com.
The rule was created manually through the Outlook interface.
My VBA code and my Outlook rule worked till now.
A problem has raised if the Sender of an email issues a Recall request to a message which now exists in Deleted Items and is marked as Read.
Then a new message is added to Deleted Items, and when my code tries to mark it as Read, I get:

Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not
support expected interface

at Item.UnRead = False
Note 1-: you can reproduce the above error by adding the above code and manually create a rule on outlook to move messages from someone e.g. your own email address to Deleted Items.
Then send an email for you and then go to Sent Item and open the message you have just sent and from Actions proceed to Recall that message.
Note 2-: I can manually mark the Recall request message as Read without any error.
Note 3-:I am using Office 2016 and Outlook is connected to an Exchange Server.
By using the below code, I found a Recall request message has type of: MailItem and MessageClass: IPM.Outlook.Recall
Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Check if the item is a MailItem and does not have a MessageClass for a recall
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set mail = Item

        ' Mark the MailItem as read
        mail.UnRead = False
    Else
        ' Log the item type and message class for further investigation
        Debug.Print "Item Type: " & TypeName(Item) & " - MessageClass: " & Item.MessageClass
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub

I tried all the below.
Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        ' If the item is a MailItem, mark it as read
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set mail = Item
        mail.UnRead = False
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        ' If the item is a MailItem, mark it as read
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set mail = Item
        mail.UnRead = False
    Else
        ' Log the item type for further investigation
        Debug.Print "Item type: " & TypeName(Item)
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    ' Optionally, you can add more logging or error-handling logic here
    Resume Next
End Sub


Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Use late binding to interact with the Item
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Dim mail As Object
        Set mail = Item

        ' Attempt to mark as read
        mail.UnRead = False
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub


Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Check if the item is a MailItem by inspecting its Class property
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        ' It's a MailItem, mark it as read
        Item.UnRead = False
    Else
        ' Log the item's class for further inspection
        Debug.Print "Item Class: " & Item.Class
    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub


For the record, I got a different error while trying to reproduce the error in the question. When I do a recall, the code inside DeletedFolder_ItemAdd does not run and I get this error message which is similar to the Run-Time error that you get, but since it's happening outside of the VBA code, I don't have the option to debug.

I don no think that Item Object is of type MailItem for the Recall message... What does Debug.Print TypeName(Item) return in such a case? Doesn't it return "ReportItem"?

The next solution works in my case:

Declare DeletedFolder on top of ThisOutlookSession code module (in the declarations area):

 Private WithEvents DeletedFolder As Outlook.Items


In the same code module use this Startup event (probably, existing...):

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  'Trash folder:
  Set DeletedFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items
End Sub


I am succesfuly using the next adapted ItemAdd event:

Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 'triggered by placing a mail in Trash folder
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Item.UnRead = False: Debug.Print "It runs for MailItem Object..."
    ElseIf TypeName(Item) = "ReportItem" Then
        Dim It As Outlook.ReportItem: Set It = Item 'just to see if `UnRead` exists between its properties (and it exists...)
        It.UnRead = False: Debug.Print "It runs for ReportItem Object..."
    End If
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
Edited:
Since, the classic method using in my case works, please check the next adapted event, able to simulate manual marking as Read, about you say it works:

Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 'to be tested when some messages are deleted and you need to mark as Read
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Item.UnRead = False: Debug.Print "It runs for MailItem..."
    ElseIf TypeName(Item) = "ReportItem" Then
        Dim It As Outlook.ReportItem: Set It = Item
        Dim delFolder As Outlook.Folder, prevCurFolder As Outlook.Folder, i As Long
         Set prevCurFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 'momorize the previous Current Folder
         Set delFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems) 'set deleted items folder
         Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = delFolder     'make deleted items folder Current Folder

         'wait a little to delFolder to really become the CurrentFolder...
         Do While i <= 100
            i = i + 1
            DoEvents
         Loop
         
        Dim OutExpl As Outlook.Explorer: Set OutExpl = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.GetExplorer
        
        If OutExpl.IsItemSelectableInView(It) Then 'if the deleted item is a selectable item:
            OutExpl.ClearSelection          'clear previous selection, if any
            OutExpl.AddToSelection It       'keep selected only the item to be marked as Read!
            If It.UnRead Then ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MarkAsRead") 'mark as Read!
            Debug.Print "It runs for ReportItem (Recall) using ExecuteMso..."
        End If
        
        Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = prevCurFolder 'select the previous selected folder...
    End If
End Sub

Please, test it and send some feedback.
If it still does not work as you need, firstly try increasing the waiting time until deleted items folder really become the (recognized) current folder (from 100 to, let us say, 200).
Since, I cannot test it on a different environment (mine) I only hope that it will behave the same on yours. It works well on my laptop.
Second EDIT:
Please, test the following event adapted to distinguish between the two types of items as in your original code. But, of course I cannot check such an event:
Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 'to be tested when some messages are deleted and you need to mark as Read
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Item.UnRead = False: Debug.Print "It runs for MailItem..."
    ElseIf TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Outlook.Recall" Then
        Dim It As Outlook.MailItem: Set It = Item
        Dim delFolder As Outlook.Folder, prevCurFolder As Outlook.Folder, i As Long
         Set prevCurFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 'momorize the previous Current Folder
         Set delFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems) 'set deleted items folder
         Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = delFolder     'make deleted items folder Current Folder

         'wait a little to delFolder to really become the CurrentFolder...
         Do While i <= 100
            i = i + 1
            DoEvents
         Loop
         
        Dim OutExpl As Outlook.Explorer: Set OutExpl = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.GetExplorer
        
        If OutExpl.IsItemSelectableInView(It) Then 'if the deleted item is a selectable item:
            OutExpl.ClearSelection          'clear previous selection, if any
            OutExpl.AddToSelection It       'keep selected only the item to be marked as Read!
            If It.UnRead Then ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MarkAsRead") 'mark as Read!
            Debug.Print "It runs for ReportItem (Recall) using ExecuteMso..."
        End If
        
        Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = prevCurFolder 'select the previous selected folder...
    End If
End Sub

Next EDIT
Please, test the next event version using Redemption. It works on my environment, you need to test it on yours:
Private Sub DeletedFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Folder As Object, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace, oRDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession, itm As Object
    
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    oRDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = olNS.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
    Set Folder = oRDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
    
    For Each itm In Folder.Items
        If itm.EntryID = Item.EntryID And itm.UnRead Then
          itm.UnRead = False 'it works in my installation...
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I tried exactly as you mentioned, the code stopped at this line Item.UnRead = False with this error (Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface). Note I am using office 2016 and outlook is connected to an Exchange Server

@Peace I am using Office 2019 installed on local computer. I don't know what policies are there in place.

I don't think it's a matter of IT Policies

@Peace It is just a supposition, I am not sure about it, neither. But, since it works on my laptop and the main difference is improbable to be related to Office version, something must bother it to behave in a different way. Unfortunately, I cannot test the issue intensively, since it works on my installation... Try stopping the event on its first code line and then press F8 to run the code line by line. Does it behave in the same way? The issue which makes me think you may be right is the fact that you are able to do it manually...

@Peace Please, try the next testing scenarios: 1. Move back to Inbox one of the recall messages (if not UnRead, make it unread). If the rule will immediately move it back see if it behaves in the same way. 2. Select such a recall messages in the deleted items folder and try processing it using ActiveExplorer. Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer myOlExp.Selection.Item(1).UnRead = False Does it raise any error?

I tried Using F8 to debug the code line by line and the same error appears (Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation…..) at the same line Item.UnRead = False. For your second comment, I could not apply , as I told you the (Recall request message) appears on Deleted Items and not in folder Inbox

@Peace Of course, not. But it is received in Inbox and moved to deleted items from there. You only simmulate the ptocess. Deleting it by the Rule or automatically...

I understood what you was means yesterday, I have stopped the rule which moving the required message to deleted folder, But Recall Request does not appear at all in Inbox Folder (The message is recalled in a hidden mode), Then I turned on  my rule again and while I am in Deleted Items Folder the Recall Request is selected and then I tried your snippet code Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer myOlExp.Selection.Item(1).UnRead = False But the same error raised again (Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support )

@Peace Is that way of appearing in hidden mode a natural one in your installation, or you did something to hide such messages? I am thinking that maybe this hiding may place the message in a specific category making it intangible also for checking UnRead.  Just a thought. I suggested the above way only to check if selecting the message this (may) solves the issue... As I said, I cannot test what's happening since I cannot reproduce the problem.

Let us try a different approach: Select such a Recall message in deleted mails folder run the next code line ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MarkAsRead"). Of course, prior to selection you should create a testing sub having the only above code line... It practically simulate a manual command. I think it may work. If it still does not work, do the same but with an ordinary mail. Just do differentiate if it is a matter of the same setting not allowing such an intervention...

Recall request appearing in hidden mode is the a natural one in my installation (All PC’s in my work are the same). I selected such a Recall message in deleted mails folder and I tried ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MarkAsRead") and It works correctly as it should, the recall request has been set as READ without any issue , BTW this code has raised an error if the message was already set as a Read.

@Peace OK, we overpass the problem of deletion, which is good news. Now,  I know how to check if  the item is UnRead and I think I know how to even select such an Item. No availability now but I will give you a sing when I will have some time to spend on the issue. I think, it would be good to work directly on your installation, if possible. I mean, to connect to your computer...

@Peace Please, check again what .MessageClass does such an item return. In my case it returns IPM.Recall.Report.Failure. You wrote IPM.Outlook.Recall. It maybe has this message clas before understanding that the mail to be recalled has been deleted. When it is in the deleted folder, does it have the same message class? Just a curiosity, I think, only to understand a little more. Otherwise, I think I can choose for reading all the ones of type ReportItem... The problem is that I really cannot test too much on my environment.

@Peace Please, check the updated event code. I think that it should also work on your environment, simulating the manual mark us Read, about you say it works..

I am afraid that It was obvious the edited code will raise an error and it really did Item.UnRead = False , I even used (the not recommended) On Error Resume Next and the Recall_request is still UnRead.

But Item.UnRead = False exists only in the code part treating the MailItem! Al the edited code treating the recalled item (ReportItem) comes after ElseIf TypeName(Item) = "ReportItem"! What and how did you test it? I cannot get you. May I connect to your computer?

Unfortunately IT prevents any connections to my PC. I already said on my question that (Recall request message) has a type of: MailItem and MessageClass: IPM.Outlook.Recall. I think if you find a way to deal with MessageClass instead of item Type

@Peace As I said, if I would modify it in this way I will not be able to test it. I ask before check again what .MessageClass does such an item return. I will try adapting the code to behave as you suggest but I suppose you understand that I cannot check anything... I will do it blind. OK, please try the adapted code. For the first run I would suggest you to place a break point on the first event code line, go down line by line (using F8) and see what's happening...

I tried your second Edit. Yes it works and (Recall request message) has set to Read, But the think the code behaves like SendKeys method (The outlook interface is flashing), I already know your code does not use SendKeys at all. Anyhow it is consider a good result till now.

@Peace What you see it is not flashing Outlook... Since, the classical way to use the item property, the actual code activates deleted mail folder window, selects the necessary item, make it Read and finally activate the initial folder. Inbox, probally. If you comment the last code line, to avoid  seselecting the initial folder, you can see  what is realy happening. The last version simulates the manual action. Only because the standard way does not work with your settings.

I have remembered that you have solved another challenging question (a long time ago) using Redemption https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

@Peace As I said many times, I do not use any Outlook automation for myself. I tried something only when tried helping somebody asking a question related to such a need. I remember that sometime I've tested Redemption, probably for you, but I do not even know if the installed application was a trial or not... Theoretically, it should not be so complicated to use it for treating a specific Outlook item. I will try what I have in my mind now, but if I will not be able to put in practice rapidly I will not deeper investigate, since, I cannot test it in an environment comparable with yours.

@Peace I will try it only because they said that Redemption is able to bypass the specific security issues. Let us hope that it is a matter of something like that...

@Peace Please test the updated event code, using Redemption. I cannot know if it will be able to solve your issue and of course, you must have Redemption installed...

Should I also need Private WithEvents DeletedFolder As Outlook.Items and the codes in `Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Trash folder:
Set DeletedFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items
End Sub`

@Peace I cannot get you. You should use all declarations and Startup event EXACTLY as I posted above. You only have to copy the above event code instead of the existing one. That's why I posted only the event code... All the mentioned issues are related only with the event triggering. Then, everything related to Redemption has been used only inside the new event code.

I tried exactly as you mentioned and Redemption is already registered on the system and has been added as a reference in VBAProject. I got the same nasty error (Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface) at this line If itm.EntryID = Item.EntryID And itm.UnRead Then

@Peace So, that is the situation... I don't know what's happening in you environment. Firstly, I would investigate why your Item is MailItem and mine is ReportItem and their.MessageClass is different, too. But not being able to reproduce the issue, I cannot do it. I am afraid that, if you really need to mark them as read you should use the solution simulating the manual process...

Let's imagine you're playing with different types of toys, and each toy has a label. You only want to play with the cars, but some toys might be broken or not cars at all. So, before you pick up a toy, you check if it's a car and if it’s not broken. If it’s not a car, you just move on without trying to play with it.
In your VBA code, you're doing something similar. You first check if the email is a normal one (a "car") by verifying if it's a MailItem and if its MessageClass is "IPM.Note". If it is, you can safely mark it as read. But if it’s something else, like a recall request (a broken toy), you just skip it to avoid any errors. This keeps your process smooth and error-free.

This is not the answer I seek.
